# How to change CardView elevation in BrowseFragment

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

In my Android TV app, I'm subclassing `BrowseFragment` and adding rows of `CardViews` using `ArrayObjectAdapter`. The selection state of the cards is by default indicated by some kind of elevation effect, making the card bigger whenever it is selected. Is it possible to control the amount of elevation or resizing? I want the card to not zoom in more than a specific amount. I already tried to set `elevation`, `cardElevation` and `cardMaxElevation` but with no effect. Does anyone know if the leanback library supports changing that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to use `setElevation` effectively through `CardViews` but I was able to change the max size of the select zoom effect when you construct the `ListRowPresenter`. One of the parameters can be  `int focusZoomFactor` and depending on the number you put in the card will zoom in greater or smaller. More on this [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/ListRowPresenter.html).

`final ListRowPresenter listRowPresenter = new ListRowPresenter(int focusZoomFactor);`

You can also turn the shadow on or off by calling `listRowPresenter.setShadowEnabled(boolean)`

Still working on the elevation specifics though!